# Wordpress change URL for same content but list by city o state wise

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm new to wordpress and i have to develop a gaming website in WP. Please give an idea or suggestion about my below question. If my grammar is wrong please forgive me.

Question :

I have to create a page name like game.php it will be come in WP www.example.com/game/

But i have to do this list by city for example : www.example.com/florida/game/ , www.example.com/las-angels/game..etc..

But the contents are same the name of the title will be the state or city name..

Is there any plugin for this ..or i don't know exact name of that..

Anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may use the query string like this

```
www.example.com/florida/game/?city=cityname&state=statename
```

then you can check in your file like this

```
if(isset($_GET['city']))
{
  // query or data based on city
}
if(isset($_GET['state']))
{
  // query or data based on state
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create categories like `florida,las-angels` etc.  and create a post named game and assign it to categories and dont forget to set the permalinks to **"Post Name"**